# Center align rotating SVG in Loader CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to animate a SVG from 0deg to 360deg. But if i use the transform: rotate property then the svg loses its position and its not centre aligned when the browser resizes. I used transform-origin to 50%. But the svg loses its position.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="hexagon-spinner">
  <Hexagon className="hexagon-loader" viewBox="0 0 65.103 75.174" />
</div>
```

```
#hexagon-spinner {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.hexagon-loader {
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  /* Things added */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: -50% 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: please share html code also..

Comment: @MinalChauhan Updated question with html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when it is `100%`, you should define `360 degrees`, not `359 degrees`.

```
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg); // ->> 360deg
  }
```

What to do about the average,

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: -50% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform-origin: -50% 50%;
  }
}
```

**Finally,**
If we need to shorten the code (since it will start with `0deg` by default), if we enter only the parameter `100%`, there will be no problem.

```
@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform-origin: -50% 50%;
  }
}
```

**Simple Code Snippet**

```css
@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform-origin: -50% 50%;
  }
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  /* Things added */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform-origin: -50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>LOADING</div>
```

```css
#hexagon-spinner {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hexagon-loader {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  /* Things added */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagon-spinner">
  <div class="hexagon-loader"></div>
</div>
```

When we shift the element with the translate (to center it) we naturally distort its center. Therefore it will not work properly.

I suggest a solution for this. (`flexbox`) is to use. You will see an example below.

Note: (Don't forget to remove Absolute and Transform Origin features)

Comment: The svg is losing its position. You can check the screenshot here 
https://ibb.co/gydtt56

Comment: Now I know you meant it. I'm adding a new example.

Comment: I was using justify center to its children the other night, now i know what i was doing wrong here. Thanks for your help !